# Is there a name for an order topology in which every base interval is non-empty?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, order-theory

Is there a name for an order topology $\tau$ over a totally ordered set $X$ that satisfies the following condition: for every $a, b \in X\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ if $a < b$, then $(a,b) \neq \emptyset$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An order [dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_order) LOTS (linearly ordered topological space, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology), e.g. ) without maximum or mininum. $\mathbb{Q}$ is the only such *countable* linear order, up to isomorphism. The absence of a minimum or maximum could be called "unbounded", I suppose. So "an unbounded order-dense LOTS"?

Comment: @RobArthan I’ll use LOTS then ( linearly ordered topological space), as is common.

Comment: Thanks. I will leave [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_order) (which I found thanks to your answer) here for future reference.

Comment: order-dense to distinguish it from topologically dense, though it does imply that the space is so-called dense-in-itself (dii).

Comment: Would you mind clarifying the acronym LOTS inside your answer, for future reference?

Comment: @EvanAad I did some edits for clarification.